# Prior sensitivity analysis: The case of a Beta prior

Tags: bayesian, prior, sensitivity-analysis

I had a question regarding how to best perform "sensitivity analysis" on a Beta prior used for a estimating a proportion from a binomially distributed data problem (i.e., beta-binomial problem).

I understand that the shape parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ move the Beta to right and left. But ***how much and on what basis*** should I change these two parameters and compare their effects on the the posterior 95% credible Intervals (picture below)?

(Note: In the picture below, 'A' parameter denotes 'alpha')

[image]

Comment: You can use a uniform prior, which is the same as a Beta(1,1) distribution. Or you can do the empirical Bayes, like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47916/bayesian-batting-average-prior).