# Estimating probability or frequency with low N?

Tags: probability, estimation, prior

I am trying to estimate the probability of an event using a low number of observations. The naive estimator

$\hat{p} =\frac{\text{number of positive observations}}{\text{total number of observations}}$

works well when the total number of observations is big enough, but if you have only a few observations, there is a decent chance that you will erroneously conclude to a 0 or 100% probability.

I suppose you could set a prior distribution on the estimated probability (say, uniform), and look for better estimators. I suppose this problem has already been tackled many times, so where should I look?

Comment: [This document](http://www.upassoc.org/upa_publications/jus/2006_may/lewis_small_sample_estimates.pdf) might be of interest. There is an [online calculator](http://www.measuringusability.com/wald.htm) that calculates point estimates and confidence intervals based on the different methods discussed in the paper.

Comment: With small N, another, but related, problem to consider is that the number of possible estimates is fairly limited. Say N=10, then there are only 11 possible estimates of $\hat{p}$: 0%, 10%, 20% ... 90%, 100%. This is probably trivial, but it is also suprising easy to overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you do actually have some prior information, the Bayesian approach might be helpful. In which case you might want to consider a Beta distribution for the prior, because this is a conjugate prior when your random variable is binomially distributed, i.e. makes the maths simple by also giving you a Beta distribution for the posterior. So with $X \sim B(n,\theta)$, and a Beta prior, $\theta \sim \mathrm{Beta}(a,b)$, then with $x$ successes in $n$ trials, your posterior is given by $\theta|x \sim \mathrm{Beta}(a + x,b + n -x)$.

The uniform distribution is a special case of the Beta distribution (for the parameters $a=b=1$). However, a uniform prior is *uninformative* (it's flat, i.e. asserts each possible value of $\theta$ is equally likely), and you don't do any better than the classical approach (in fact I believe you essentially get the same point estimate / credible interval). So if you don't have any prior information, it looks like [@COOLSerdash's link in the comment on your question](http://www.upassoc.org/upa_publications/jus/2006_may/lewis_small_sample_estimates.pdf) is the way to go to get appropriate point estimates / confidence intervals.

Note that in Bayesian statistics, [credible intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) have the same role as the confidence intervals of classical statistics. If you don't have any prior beliefs (your prior is uninformative, or non-informative), your credible intervals will, under certain conditions, correspond to the confidence intervals you would have got from a classical approach.

Comment: +1 and a short note for @static_rtti: see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58792/21054) for a complete worked-out example using the $\mathrm{Beta}$ for proportions.

Comment: One thing I don't understand about your answer: you say the uniform distribution is uninformative. However if I look at the expected value of the posterior beta distribution, it already looks like a better estimator than my naive one. Am I correct?

Comment: @static_rtti This is a question in itself! Briefly, Bayesian statistics says how beliefs should change when you get new data. So if, e.g., you have a strong belief about θ and get only a few data points, your belief won't be changed much by the data. But if you have a weak belief about θ and you get lots of data, your belief will change according to the data. If you have no beliefs, i.e. think all possible values of θ are equally likely (uniformly distributed), then you have an uninformative prior and your posterior is completely determined by the data, just as a classical confidence interval.

Comment: @static_rtti You might want to take a look at this question and its answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64259/what-is-meant-by-a-uniform-prior.