# MLE == MAP under Uniform Prior?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bayes

Does Maximum Likelihood Estimation always yield the same result as Maximum a Posteriori with uniform prior?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64259/how-does-a-uniform-prior-lead-to-the-same-estimates-from-maximum-likelihood-and