# Bayes estimator with k-letter alphabet?

Tags: bayesian, estimation

I have a set of $n$ realizations $y_j \in \{a,b,c,...\}$ in an alphabet with $k$ symbols.

Each letter from this alphabet has an unknown prior probability $x_i$. The goal is to estimate $\mathbb{x}$ from the observations $\mathbb{y}$ so as to minimize the [mean square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_squared_error).

I assume the probabilities $x_i$ follow a uniform distribution, with the constraint that $\sum_{i}{x_i}=1$.

I already know that the case where the alphabet has only two letters is called the bayes estimator with beta prior, which has [well-known solutions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/estimating-probability-or-frequency-with-low-n). However, I'm at loss for the more general case with $k$ letters.

Any insight?

Comment: If your data come from a multinomial distribution then the Dirichlet distribution is the conjugate prior, which generalizes the Beta distribution to $K$ dimensions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Conjugate_to_categorical.2Fmultinomial

Comment: @jerad - might want to expand that a little and make it an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @jerad: I unfortunately don't think the Dirichlet prior applies, because of the constraint that the prior probabilities must sum up to one. Of course I'd love to be proven wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out @jerad was right: the problem works out very nicely with a Dirichlet prior distribution. [This pdf](http://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/9252/1/TR001375.pdf) answers the question in-depth.

In the end, with a uniform prior distribution, the minimum mean square estimator is:

$p_i = \frac{n_j+1}{n+k}$

Where $n_j$ is the number of times the j-eth symbol has been observed.