# How do I choose parameters for my beta prior?

Tags: prior, beta-distribution

Suppose today I'm going to flip a coin.  I believe that 9 of 10 flips will come up heads.  I flip the coin and 8 of 10 are heads.  Is my distribution of belief

1. beta(9+8, 1+2)
2. beta(1+9+8, 1+1+2)
3. beta(m+8, n+2) where I choose m and n based on graphing beta(m,n) and deciding if it feels right.  (This is not a facetious answer, it's a real suggestion.)
4. Hidden option 4.

If I use #1, I believe that is an [improper prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors), but Wikipedia claims some statisticians use them.

This choice is not obvious to me.

Comment: If you want your prior to include the information of a *hypothetical sample* of 10 flips out of which 9 came out as heads, then your prior is $\mathrm{Beta}(9,1)$. The mean of the prior is $0.9$. After flipping the coin 10 times out of which 8 are heads, your posterior is $\mathrm{Beta}(17,3)$. The posterior mean is $0.85$. You can use an improper prior, that is no problem. The Beta distribution is the conjugate distribution of the binomial. Check out [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58792/21054) for a fully worked example using the Beta distribution.

Comment: Choice #1 is not an improper prior.

Comment: @QuantIbex Your right, of course (+1). Sorry, my wording was inaccurate: I didn't want to imply that #1 was improper, I just wanted to say that an improper prior is not a problem automatically, at least not mathematically.

Comment: For the Beta distribution, the improper prior is $\lim_{a \to 0}\rm{Beta(a,a)}$. Improper means it isn't a probability density, e.g. doesn't integrate to 1. You might want to consider a non-informative prior, which is flat for all possible values of your parameter: the uniform distribution is suitable here, which is a special case of the Beta distribution, i.e. $\rm{Beta(1,1)}$.    See [online beta graphing](http://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?id=system/2006/1180573226).

Comment: @COOLSerdash In fact, my comment was in response to the OP's statement. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Improper priors are acceptable so long as they produce proper *posteriors*. For the beta prior with a binomial likelihood, any improper prior will produce a proper posterior provided you observe one (or more) heads and one (or more) tails.

Answer (score 13):

If your prior belief is that 9 of the 10 coin flips will come up heads, then you want the expectation of your prior to be 0.9. Given $X \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ (for conjugacy in the beta-binomial model), then $E[X] = \alpha/(\alpha+\beta) = 0.9$, so you can use this as your first constraint. Obviously this leaves you with an infinite number of possibilities, so we'll need a second constraint which will represent your subjective confidence in this prior belief: the variance of your prior, $\operatorname{var}[X] = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}\ $

Decide how you want to set your variance and solve the system of equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to define the parameters for your prior. Justifying your choice of variance here may be difficult: you can always err on the side of a wider (i.e. less informative) variance. The wider you set the variance, the closer your prior will approximate a uniform distribution.

If you want a <s>truly</s> uninformative prior, you should consider using [Jeffrey's Prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior).

Comment: There is no such thing as a [trully uninformative prior](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information).

Comment: Ok, that's fair. I consider it a 'very effective' uninformative prior, but you're right, I shouldn't be using such rigid/suggestive language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The gist is: you have to say something about the variance to set the parameters.  Seems sensible.  I think the human-understandable way to approach it might be "I believe the mean is 0.9, and >0.8 with 95% confidence." It would be interesting to see the easiest way to do that.

Comment: By the way, I could not make heads or tails of Jeffrey's Prior.  I'm sure it's very important and useful, but I won't worry about it.

Comment: @dfrankow here's a better explanation: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture7.pdf