# Normal prior for Binomial likelihood

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior

Pardon my ignorance, i am new to Bayesian Analysis.

I am trying to use Normal prior for a binomial likelihood,  which of these are most likely candidates        ( $\bar{x} $, $ \mu $, $ \sigma $ ) for prior and most likely candidates for constants ? Please advise.

Comment: $\bar{x}$ is not a parameter of the normal distribution (it's the maximum-likelihood estimate of $\mu$)

Comment: It seems to me like your question does not make much sense as it stands now. Perhaps you'd benefit from reading introductory chapters/papers to the Bayesian approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the likelihood follows a binomial distribution, your [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) is the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Please check [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782) on the intuition of beta distribution.

After reading that answer, note that `Beta(a, b)` distribution can be [approximated by the Normal distribution](http://www.vosesoftware.com/ModelRiskHelp/index.htm#Distributions/Approximating_one_distribution_with_another/Normal_approximation_to_the_Beta_distribution.htm) when a and b are sufficiently large.

You can play with a Beta distribtuion on [this link](http://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?id=system/2006/1180573226). As you incraese `a` and `b`, the pdf looks more and more like the normal distribution.