# What is the intuition behind Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: dirichlet-distribution, intuition

looking for explanation on similar lines 
[What is the intuition behind beta distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution)

Comment: This question and answer can be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244917/what-exactly-is-the-alpha-in-the-dirichlet-distribution