# How can I (numerically) approximate the quantile in a beta distribution in SQL?

Tags: bayesian, excel, beta-distribution, multiarmed-bandit, sql

I wrote some code in SAS that among other things, used the [BETAINV function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543441.htm) (or BETA.INV as it's called in Microsoft Excel) to calculate the quantile in a beta distribution corresponding to a random input value. Now I'm looking for a way to calculate this in **SQL** (on Netezza).

It doesn't have to be super precise, I'm more concerned about **speed**, as this function has to be called 2 billion times per day.

What is the **use case** exactly? I'm interested in estimating click-through rates, and acting upon that knowledge. In fact, I'm building a Bayesian Bandit 'machine' that optimizes click-through rates by 'exploring' the performance of different messages. See [this article](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/bayesian_bandit.html) for more information.

So, given for example the fact that we saw 20 clicks in 2000 views, the click-through rate is 1%. Now this value is just an estimate, because we sampled only 2000 people. The 'real' CTR is somewhere around 1% but probably not exactly 1%. The probability distribution for a CTR turns out to be a beta distribution.

[image]

Now I want to pull a **random value** from this **distribution** (2 billion times per day). So I want most of those random values to be around the 1% in this case, but sometimes it may be lower or higher. That's exactly what the BETAINV function does. You give it a uniform random variable between 0 and 1 and it gives you the respective quantile in the beta distribution.

There's no BETAINV function in Netezza, so can I approximate this in some way (Taylor expansion?) to calculate this in a fast way?

Note: alpha and beta in my case are always integers, with alpha equal to the number of clicks and beta equal to the number of non-clicks. Alpha is always smaller than beta. Alpha can be between 1 and say 100,000. Beta can be between 1 and say 10,000,000.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You're not talking about something called "the inverse beta distribution" (in fact the "inverse beta distribution" would be a shifted beta prime distribution). Instead you seem to be talking about the inverse of the cdf of a beta distribution, also called the quantile function of the beta distribution. [When you say "turns out to be a beta distribution", where is the derivation for this?]

Comment: You're correct. I changed the title accordingly. As for why click-through rate probabilities are beta distributions... the following shows a very similar reasoning: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution. I'll see if I can find an even clearer 'proof'.

Comment: Basically this is what I'm trying to do: https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/bayesian_bandit.html. This link clearly explains why beta distributions can be used to model CTR probabilities and explains exactly the use case I'm going for here. The author uses a Python script to get random values from the distribution. I need to do it in Netezza (SQL).

Comment: You really should have explained in your question you were using a Bayesian approach and should probably have selected it as a tag. *That* makes it clear where the beta comes from -- at least the likelihood results in a beta. You should also discuss your prior.

Comment: Since the question is more about coding than statistics, shouldn`t it be moved to the sister site?