# Bayesian posterior and prior distribution question

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

Here is my question:

You want to find proportion x of phones from a given company is defective. You are sent a box of 10 samples, and you find that two are defective.

1. Compute the posterior distribution for x using a uniform prior distribution.

2.Some time later, you are sent a second batch of 10 phones from the same company, but a different model. You find that three examples are defective in this new batch. Compute the updated posterior distribution. (One the includes the estimate obtained from the first batch).

I am not sure how to calculate the exact value of the first question since I got a beta(3,8) on question1. Also, for question2, how can I use the posterior distribution(beta(3,8))in question 1 to update the new posterior question? (I am also not sure whether using binomial distribution or beta distribution for this question)Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a problem with question 1? Look at what it's asking from you. For question 2, think about what you want to use as a prior distribution to compute the posterior. Do you still want to use a uniform prior? Or do you want that prior to reflect knowledge you have gained in the past?

Comment: I want to use the knowledge gained from the first question, and for question1, is there any way to get a numerical value, apart from beta(3,8)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read through [What is the intuition behind beta distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution) you'll find an explanation. (Or actually, several explanations from various viewpoints. The question itself is broader than yours, but several answers give examples.)

Several answers use a baseball analogy, and in case you're not familiar with baseball, the idea is that you are "at bat" a certain number of times in a game and some number of those times at bat you succeed and manage to get a "hit". You thus have two numbers representing your "at bat performance" in a baseball game, which correspond to your example problem: "at bat" corresponds to your number of samples, "hit" corresponds to your number of defects.