# Conditional beta posterior for uniform priors

Tags: probability, bayesian, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I have three different random variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ . These random variables are actually parameters of binomial likelihood

1. Assume that I have prior distribution of $\theta_2 \sim Uniform (0,1)$
2. But prior distribution of $\theta_3 \sim Uniform (\theta_2,1)$ and prior distribution of $\theta_1 \sim Uniform (0,\theta_2)$

Is there a way I could find the posterior distribution of $ \theta_1,\theta_3$ given that I have data (Binomial likelihood) and prior information as given above?

$f(\theta_3|x_3) = \frac{Likelihood(x_3|\theta_3)\times Prior(\theta_3|\theta_3>=\theta_2)}{P(x_3)} = Beta(\alpha_3,\beta_3)$

So basically I want to find the parameters for this conditional posterior distribution

Comment: Plug it into MCMC sampler and it’ll give you the result. What’s the problem? How is it related to beta distribution mentioned in the title?

Comment: @Tim I need to find a posterior distribution for the thetas. For uniform prior, the posterior is Beta Distribution

Comment: @Tim I edited the question a bit. Im not much familiar with MCMC sampler. Can you please give me a lead?

Answer (score 3):

*You can't.* The posterior would follow beta distribution if you used [beta-binomial model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution) with the likelihood being a binomial distribution and beta distribution as a prior. In such a case, beta is a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for binomial and we have a closed-form solution for the posterior that happens to be also a beta distribution. However it *is not* the case that other models with parameters on unit interval will have beta distribution as a posterior.

In your case, just use probabilistic programming like [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) or [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/) to define the model and sample from it using MCMC (see [mcmc](/questions/tagged/mcmc) for more details) to learn the distribution of the parameters. It is a pretty standard solution for estimating posterior distributions for Bayesian models.

Comment: All likelihoods (1, 2 and 3) are Binomial and all priors are uniform. Its just that the Priors are conditional. Won't it still give a beta posterior?

Comment: Also I use R language. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Uniform priors do not lead to beta posteriors. Beta distribution assigns non-zero probabilities to values in (0, 1) interval, your priors don't, so they cannot get beta as a posterior. There is an R package for Stan, but it is an independent language you'd need to learn https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html