# does Thompson sampling for price optimisation require discriminative pricing

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

I get the gist of Thompson sampling for price optimisation (I think - see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QDOTtRxfbg) around minute 31). I wonder, would Thompson sampling require discriminative pricing or can prices be change sequentially during the day? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by discriminative pricing?

Comment: It means that n customers could encounter m different prices at a/the same point in time. This illegal in many countries - also the EU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by discriminative pricing you mean

> that n customers could encounter m different prices at a/the same point in time

then it's not a problem. You would sample the price for a *batch* of customers and given the outcomes, you would make the Bayesian update. For example, in the case of Bernoulli bandit, for a single customer, if no purchase was observed, [the update would be](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782) $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta+1)$, if you observed $m$ purchases and $k$ cases without purchase, the update would just be $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha + m, \beta+k)$. The same applies to continuous rewards, you just need to make an update that considers multiple samples.

Comment: Thanks. So 1 price per batch, let us n hours? Then change price for next n hours?

Comment: @cs0815 how you conduct the experiment would depend on many technical, business, or legal reasons. What I'm saying is that it is technically possible to do the multi-sample updates, no reason why this would not be possible.