# Baysian Inference with beta-binomial model with different number of trials

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, binomial-distribution

Let's imagine that we have created and estimated a posterior with a beta prior and binomial likelihood function. The posterior is given by $p(\mu |D) = Beta(2,99)$. Now, I want to do inference with that model. But the number of trials has changed and I want to know the probability of having 3 success from 40 trials. Can I still use that estimated model, i.e., will just plugging in $\mu$ from $Beta(2,99)$ into $Binom(3|\mu, 40)$ work?

I was looking at a Bernoulli example and there it is clear. We have Bernoulli distribution parameterized as $Bern(x| \mu)$ so just one parameter $\mu$. In the Binomial case it is $Binom(x|\mu, N)$ so `N` is also playing a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You observed some Binomial data and ended up with a posterior of $\mathrm{Beta}(2,99)$ for your parameter $\mu$, which I assume is the probability of success.

If you wanted to give a point estimate for $\mu$, you could choose to use the posterior mean, which is $\hat{\mu}=2/(2+99)=0.0198$ (or, alternatively, the posterior median or mode).

You are now going to observe a further 40 trials; let $X$ be the number of successes. You are interested in the probability of observing exactly 3 successes, which is equal to
$$
\mathrm{P}(X=3|\mu)={40 \choose 3} \mu^3 (1-\mu)^{40-3}
$$
While you could plug your point estimate into the formula, this is not quite right, as it does not take into account the uncertainty around $\mu$.

What you should do is compute
$$
\int_0^1 \mathrm{P}(X=3|\mu) f(\mu) d\mu
$$
where $f(\mu)$ is your posterior (Beta) density for $\mu$. In other words, you want to integrate $\mu$ out of the joint mass/density of $X$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you @Doctor Milt. Indeed, I am interested in doing Bayesian inference and I do not want to use point estimates (Maximum a posteriori estimates aka MAP). 

I found a similart formula (and I understand the logic behind it) to the last one you posted. It is for Bernnoulli case $$ p(x=1|D) = \int_{0}^{1} p(x=1|\mu) p(\mu|D) d\mu = \int_{0}^{1} \mu p( \mu | D) $$.

Comment: For Binomial case, I am not sure how to write it down nicely 

$$ p(x=3|D, 40) = \int_{0}^{1} p(x=3|\mu, 40) p(\mu|D, 101) d\mu $$.

This does not feel right since I have the posterior that has a parameter $N$=101 (2success + 99 failures) and the probability that I am trying to estimate is for $N$=40.

Comment: (you can ignore $D$ in the formula's above)

Comment: Hi @AntonKerel, the fact that your original experiment had 101 trials is already encoded in your posterior distribution for $\mu$. 

The number of trials in the new experiment ($N=40$) is just a fixed parameter. You know that the conditional distribution for the outcome you care about is $X|\mu \sim \mathrm{Bin}(40, \mu)$, but you want the marginal distribution.

To get this, you need to integrate out $\mu$, i.e. average over all possible values of $\mu$ according to your posterior distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow you, but as I understand your question you observed $k$ successes in $n$ trials and used this data in a [beta-binomial model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#47782). If your prior was $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, then the posterior is $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha + k, \beta + n-k)$. Now, let's go one step back, your model is

$$\begin{align}
\mu &\sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) \\
X_n &\sim \mathsf{Bin}(\mu, n)
\end{align}$$

where $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ for $Y_i \underset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathsf{Bern}(\mu)$. In plain English, you assume that $\mu$ is the probability of "success" for $n$ independent [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). The sum of the ones and zeros from the Bernoulli trials $X_n$ makes a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). If now you want to make a guess on the number of successes in $m \ne n$ independent Bernoulli trials, you can just plug in $\mu$ into the binomial distribution $\mathsf{Bin}(\mu, m)$. The trials are identical and independent, so it is like tossing a coin $m$ times instead of $n$, each individual toss behaves the same regardless of how many times you toss.

You can also look at it through the lens of [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties). The expected value of a single Bernoulli trial is $E[Y_i] = \mu$, for $n$ trials it is $E[nY_i] = n E[Y_i] = n\mu$ and for $m$ trials $m\mu$. Those correspond to the means of the binomial distributions.

So yes, you just plug in the estimated $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. Sorry for a question that is a bit confusing. 
You almost understood my question. I can rephrase it a bit. 

I want to produce a (biased) Bayesian esimator of probability of having 3 successes in 40 tosses *given* the posterior distribution that I have estimated before. In my mind, Bayesian model always produces a probability of some sort. You can then use the pdf of the posterior to do inference. Therefore, I am interested in the probability of success for `40 choose 3` given that my coin priorly has been estimate to follow $Beta(2,99)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @AntonKerel so you want to know what is the probability of seeing 3 successes in 40 trials given that the probability of success is $\mu$ given the posterior beta distribution? This is what I described.